# Как вывести значения для группы через запятую

Tags: php, mysql, sql

есть такая таблица, idcode - это один товар(их много). Как из бд не выводить name похожего idcode но выводить все size.

```
id | name | idcode | size
1 | Hello | 1111 | 12
2 | Hello | 1111 | 13
2 | Hello | 1111 | 14
```

То есть желаемый результат:

> Hello 1111 12,13,14

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используем функцию GROUP_CONCAT вместе с группировкой

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(idcode)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: Ответ у вас с ошибкой.

Comment: @Visman Не вижу

Answer (score 0):

В ответе выше неверно указаны колонки и нет сортировки. Правильно так:

```
SELECT name, idcode, GROUP_CONCAT(size ORDER BY size)
FROM table1
GROUP BY name, idcode;
```