# SQL: Как положить несколько значений в одно поле таблицы?

Tags: sql

Коллеги, у меня вопрос.

У меня есть таблица tasks, есть таблица comments, у comment есть task_id, связь one-to-many.

```
+-------------------------+
|                 comments|
+--+-------+--------------+
|id|task_id|          text|
+--+-------+--------------+
| 1|      1|первый коммент|
+--+-------+--------------+
| 2|      1|второй коммент|
+--+-------+--------------+
```

Стоит задача сделать плоскую таблицу, для этого мне нужно в новой таблице task_views в поле comments добавить все связанные комменты через строку.

```
+-----------------------------------+
|                         task_views|
+--+--------------------------------+
|id|                        comments|
+--+--------------------------------+
| 1|первый коммент\n\nвторой коммент|
+--+--------------------------------+
```

Я выполняю приблизительно такой скрипт, чтобы наполнить таблицу:

```
insert into task_views (id, comments)
select t.id,
       ???
from tasks t
        left join comments c on t.comment_id = comments.id;
```

Подскажите, как мне составить запрос, чтобы сконкатенировать тексты в одно поле должным образом?

Comment: Пожалуйста, указывайте СУБД в метках или в теле вопроса.

Comment: И не только СУБД, но ещё и версию. И то, и другое - ВАЖНО.

Comment: MySQL: `group_concat()`, oracle: `listagg()`, ms sql, posgresql: `string_agg()`. Но в разных версиях тех же СУБД могут быть другие функции/подходы

Comment: @Mike а как будет выглядеть полный запрос? MySQL и Oracle

Comment: это обычные агрегатные функции. "сумма строк" для числового поля что бы получить сумму вы бы написали sum(поле),  не забыв сделать group by, тут то же самое

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вывести значения для группы через запятую](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/717976/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d1%8b-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%83%d1%8e)